# Can't Play AudioClips via Addressable Asset System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Problem**

I get AudioClip via Addressable Asset System and pass it to AudioSource for playback. If I set the PlayMode to Use Asset Database, it plays fine, but if I specify Use Existing Build, it doesn't play.
Please help me.

Things I tried

1. I did New Build > Default Build Script from Addressable Group window, but the situation does not improve. In addition, even if Clean Build is executed, it is the same.
2. I thought that the acquisition itself is not done, and I displayed the name of AudioClip acquired with DebugLog, but it is displayed normally, and acquisition is thought to be done well.
   But when I look at it in the editor, AudioClip is not registered in AudioSource and VoiceTrack.clip = clip is not completed normally.
3. I tried switching the AssetBundleCompression setting to UnCompressed, but it had no effect.

**Versions**

- Unity Version 2021.3.10f1
- Addressables Version 1.19.19

**Code** in the relevant section

main.cs

```
public async UniTask ExecuteAsync(CallInstReference reference, InstRunner runner, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    AudioClip clip = await Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<AudioClip>(clipAddress.Get());
    reference.world.callSoundManager.PlayVoice(clip, duration );
        Addressables.Release(clip);
    }
```

callSoundManager.cs

```
    public void PlayVoice( AudioClip clip , float duration = 0.2f , bool loop = false)
    {
        Debug.Log(clip.name + " voiceStart"); //currect clip name displayed.
        VoiceTrack.clip = clip; //no clip attached the audioSource in Editor
        VoiceTrack.loop = loop;
        VoiceTrack.Play();
        VoiceTrack.DOFade(1f, duration);

    }
```

If anything is missing, please comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the "callback way"

```
public class AddressableClipPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource source;

    [SerializeField]
    private AssetReference audioClip;

    private void Start()
    {
        audioClip.LoadAssetAsync<AudioClip>().Completed += OnAudioClipLoaded;
    }

    private void OnAudioClipLoaded(AsyncOperationHandle<AudioClip> handle)
    {
        source.clip = handle.Result;
        source.Play();
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        audioClip.ReleaseAsset();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably add a check in OnAudioClipLoaded that neither the script nor Audio source has been destroyed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Self resolved. I tryed

> AudioClip clip = await Addressables.LoadAssetAsync(clipAddress.Get());

but it seems I needed to take out the handle and wait for a separate Task. Sorry for the trouble. The following code works fine.

> AsyncOperationHandle handle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync(key); await
> handle.Task;
>
> if (handle.Status == AsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded)
> result = handle.Result;